# Permutation matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations

Given a permutation matrix $P$, is it true that there exist a natural number $n$ such that if $P$ is multiplied $n$ times, it gives the identity matrix (i.e., $\underbrace{P \times P \times \ldots \times P}_{n 
~\text{times}} = I$)?

If so, I am looking for a proof and possibly an efficient way to find out the smallest soltion for $n$. Otherwise, a counterexample will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Every permutation matrix or order $n\times n$ corresponds to a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$. Now ask yourself, does every permutation have a finite order? Why/Why not ?

Comment: @spkakkar It has, right?

Comment: Try drawing out a permutation, as arrows between numbers. That should give you a representation of that permutation as disjoint cycles. Now try figuring out what power you need to take the permutation to, to get back to the identity.

Comment: @pushpen.paul YES.

Comment: @Joppy The product of the cardinality of each cycle?